# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, mysql

Intento hacer la consulta a la base de datos para ingresar los datos del input a la BDD estoy crendo un login sencillo con PHP y MySQL, soy algo nuevo en esto así que no entiendo muy bien la razón de este error, este es el codigo.

```html
<?php
 require 'database.php';

 $message = '';

 if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
   $stat = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stat->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
   //Cifrar la contraseña
   $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
   $stat->bindParam(':password', $password);

   if ($stat->execute()) {
     $message = 'Succesfully created new user';
   }else{
     $message = 'Sorry we cannot create your account';
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: El del título, se supone que tendría que agregar el email y la contraseña a la Base de Datos, pero no lo hace

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. El error me parece que no es de ahí, estás usando `count` de PHP en otra parte sobre un objeto que no es *contable*, revisa la línea que te indica el mensaje de error.

Comment: De hecho me parece curioso porque no he usado la función count(), el error me lo da en el Phpmyadmin

Comment: Muyyy raro. El código que muestras parece correcto. ¿Revisaste lo que hay en `database.php`?